# конвертация из String в int в Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

Изучаю фреймворк Vaadin. Столкнулся с проблемой преобразования String в int. Вот сам код:

```
TextField name = new TextField();
int num;
num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(name));
Paragraph greeting = new Paragraph("");
Button button = new Button("Result", event -> {
    greeting.setText(" " + num * 500);
});
add(name, button, greeting);
```

А вот ошибка:

```
There was an exception while trying to navigate to '' with the exception message 'Error creating bean with name 'com.gmail.ilim.MainView': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.gmail.ilim.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""'
```

Comment: А как вы думаете, если у вас поле пустое, к какому числу он это должен преобразовать?

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, что если строка null или пустая, то вы хотите передавать 0.
Если это так, то воспользуйтесь org.apache.commons.lang3

```
Integer.valueOf(StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(name.getText(), "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField name = new TextField();
Paragraph greeting = new Paragraph("");
Button button = new Button("Result", event -> {
     int num;
     try {
         num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(name.getValue()));
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         num = 0; // your default value
         // you should also let the user know he didnt enter a valid number
         Notification.show("Please enter a valid number");
     }
     greeting.setText(" " + num * 500);
 });
 add(name, button, greeting);
```